# Should I search on Internet before asking question?

Tags: discussion, search, asking-questions, beta-sites

Hinduism beta site is being recently launched. I am seeing many question on this site whose answer are simply available in the first google search result.

We have definition about asking a good question with proper searching on net, showing some effort ( code ) and error ( if any ).

Should such rule apply to beta sites as well ? When I ask this question on [meta site](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/224/467) I got reply as we should allow such questions to build up the good question database.

So are such question's allow on beta site to build up the good question database on site or not ?

I am not against of such question, I just want to get clarification to make site better since it's childhood.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't 'seed' your site - ask questions pertaining to *real life problems that you face*. Make them *interesting*, make them *captivating* and always favor *depth over breadth*. When your site opens to the public and people begin promoting it to the very experts that can make it a resounding success, *you want those experts to have something to do*.

Other people will ask plenty of basic questions on your site once it opens, leave that to them. You, the folks trying to get your site off the ground *must* take care to set the highest level possible when it comes to the types of questions you want to see on the site.

Otherwise? You end up with lay people Google searching questions from other lay people and pasting someone else's content as the large part of their answer. That's not what the site should be about. Make it your own, and make it interesting. As long as your quality and participation remain reasonably high, we'll give you extra time to come up with more questions if you need it in the private beta phase, and 'as long as it takes' once in public beta.

Comment: Thanks, This will help others ( Hinduism users ) too to create good healthy site :)

Answer (score 5):

Mr. Alien hits the nail on the head with [his answer](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/225) (emphasis added):

> The site is in Beta and we are building a solid database of good questions and answers, **not the general or basic ones**.

You're trying to attract a community of *experts* during your site's beta phase. Asking lots of general or basic questions won't accomplish that goal. You want to populate the site with a good set of well-researched questions so that experts in the field will be motivated to participate.

Comment: This ^^^^^. Thanks, Bill.

Comment: Sorry but I didnt get your answer.

Comment: @Kedarnath If you easily find your answer via Google search, don't post it on a beta site here. You don't want to flood your beta with these kinds of questions. If you do, experts in the subject will think the site is for beginners and will be less likely to participate.

Comment: @Kedarnath, if you follow this advice the site will hold quality content. Nevertheless, general questions will appear anyway. That is why they need to be combated, so they will not take over.

Comment: @AndreSilva of course, I am already aware this rule. But seeing many easy question on the site I got doubt. So I asked this question. I too want quality content only.